# Configuring TLS and SSL for AWS Fargate Cube.js Server with NLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, cube

I'd like to achieve the following:

AWS and Cube Setup: What configurations are needed to achieve this?

###### AWS Configuration:

- Network Load Balancer (NLB) with public access, forwarding TCP traffic on port 54321 to the Cube container.
- Cube container running on AWS Fargate in a private subnet.
- MySQL database container running on AWS Fargate in a private subnet.
  Cube accesses the database on port 3306.

###### Current Status:

- Cube's access to the database is already encrypted.
- A DB client tool or BI tool can connect to the database container through the Cube container using TCP.

###### Conditions:

- The DB client tool or BI tool needs to connect to Cube (54321) using a PostgreSQL connector.
- Encrypt the connection from the DB client tool or BI tool to Cube (54321) using TLS.
- Establish an SSL connection from the DB client tool or BI tool through the Cube container to the database container.

Comment: I think your question is more about setting it up for personal use, try asking in: [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If it's for setting up your business infrastructure, then try in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).